# How to keep workspace in sync across multiple computers in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

Not sure if 'workspace' is the correct terminology here, but basically I am on a team that uses TFS and I would like to be able to work on my laptop or my home computer in addition to my work computer.

As long as I check all my changes in this isn't a problem, but sometimes at the end of the day I'm in the middle of working on something and it's not ready to be checked in. Is shelving my changes the best way to be able to get at them from another computer, or is there any other solution for keeping my workspace in sync from one pc to the next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the only solution is Shelving. If you Shelve your work on ConputerA you will be able to retrieve the code on computerB.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: From what I understand, after shelving a file that is "checked out", its status does not change. I.e., it will still be locked out by someone on the first machine and might be inaccessible to you on another machine, even when using the same account for TFS!